# Is uploading a file using a download task for background transfert a good thing?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I need to upload files in background for my application.

So i looked uploadtask method but it actually need a fileurl to work with background transfert.
It won't really be a big deal to put my object in JSON/XML and save it as a file but it would need a change in my server side.

However, i notice that there is a way to upload file using the downloadtask which additionally return the body response.

Basically, i would create my object in memory and adding it as NSData (byte[]) in my download request.
It actually worked but i fear that there may be memory/connection bug since it's not only file on disk but also memory and we 
are in a background status...

Is this a correct way to do it ?? or i may have connection problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: i think you must accept Leonardo's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay, this is [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44)

> Uploading a File Using a Download Task
>
> To upload body content for a download task, your app must provide
>   either an NSData object or a body stream as part of the NSURLRequest
>   object provided when it creates the download request.
>
> If you provide the data using a stream, your app must provide a
>   URLSession:task:needNewBodyStream: delegate method to provide a new
>   body stream in the event of an authentication failure. This method is
>   described further in Uploading Body Content Using a Stream.
>
> The download task behaves just like a data task except for the way in
>   which the data is returned to your app.

Comment: I need more than "I think" perpective :D